# How to split a String from reverse where first character is found in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like MH12PE1433 I am trying to finding a regular expression to split it from the end where I got the first character for eg.

```
String str1=1433;
String str2=MH12PE;
```

I am able to split last 4 digits by using

```
String no=MH12PE1433;
if (no.length() > 3) {
                        text2 = no.substring(no.length() - 4);
}
```

but want to split using regular expression where the first alphabet is found.
 I hope you understood my question 
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if `regress` is related to regular expression.  Did you mean RegEx?

Comment: is string of format {2 char}{2 digits}{2 chars}{4 digits}?

Comment: will the numbers always have the same length?

Comment: ```first alphabet is found``` should this be ```first VOWEL is found```? since if ```first alphabet is found``` then your split will be on ```M```

Comment: @Stultuske length would be variable either 6 digits 8 digits 10 digits but the concept is whenever find the first character from reverse side String got split.

Comment: so, you are "able to split last 4 digits", but it won't always be 4 digits.

Comment: @Mark any alphabet from A to Z.

Comment: @AbhishekBhardwaj So what will be the condition of the split? what do you mean whenever the ```first alphabet is found``` then?

Comment: @Mark as I mentioned above like MH54BE8569 I want the output 8569 and MH54BE

Comment: @AbhishekBhardwaj then it is not ```first alphabet is found``` it is ```last alphabet is found```

Comment: @Mark from the reverse side when first character is found hope you get my point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex to split the way you want,

```
(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d+$)
```

Here `(?<=[A-Z])` positive lookbehind marks the start of first alphabet and `(?=\d+$)` marks the start of continuous digits till end of string, hence giving you the point inside string you are looking for. Just splitting with that point will give you your desired output.

Java code,

```
String s = "MH12PE1433";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=[A-Z])(?=\\d+$)")));
```

Prints,

```
[MH12PE, 1433]
```

You can also play with the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/C4UgBT/1)

Also, in case you have any non-alphabet string and not just numbers at the end of string, you can more generally use this regex, which will split your text from the last alphabet (as you say first alphabet from end of string).

```
(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z]*$)
```

Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("MH12PE1433","MH12PE@@1123", "MH12PE@@##$$", "MH12Pe5555");
list.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " --> " + Arrays.toString(x.split("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z]*$)"))));
```

Prints,

```
MH12PE1433 --> [MH12PE, 1433]
MH12PE@@1123 --> [MH12PE, @@1123]
MH12PE@@##$$ --> [MH12PE, @@##$$]
MH12Pe5555 --> [MH12Pe, 5555]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:
a. Replace all digits from end using following code to get the earlier string.
b. Replace the derived String from original to gets the digits at the end.

```
String no="MH12PE1433";
    String regex="[0-9]+$";//all ending digits
    String prefix = no.replaceFirst(regex, "");//MH12PE
    String suffix = no.replaceFirst(prefix, "");//1433
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex that matches digits `[0-9]+` at the end of the string by adding a `$` at the end of the regex.

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)$");

private String extractTrailingDigits(String s) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

private void test() {
    String[] tests = {"MH12PE1433", "MH12PE1433000"};
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println(test + " -> " + extractTrailingDigits(test));
    }
}
```